# Creating pandas DataFrame columns from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created a df which looks as follows:

```
   a    b    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  x   NaN   .    .    .    .    .   NaN
1  y    .              .              .
2  .    .              .              .
.  .    .    .    .   NaN   .    .    .
.  .    .              .              .
.  .    .              .              .
N  z   NaN   .    .    .    .    .   NaN
```

For each value in column a(x...z), I have an additional DataFrame(stored in a map `{'x':df1, ..., 'z':df2}`, with 2 columns. the first one(Call it M) has the values 1...6, and the second one(Call it N), some other values.

Illustration(for some value in 'a' column, assume 'x'):

```
   M    N
   1   bla
   2   bla1
   3   bla2
   4   bla3
   5   bla4
   6   bla5
```

so I want to fill the row of 'x'(in the first df) s.t col 1 will get 'bla', col 2 - 'bla1' and so on.

```
   a    b    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  x   NaN  bla  bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 bla5
1  y    .              .              .
2  .    .              .              .
.  .    .    .    .   NaN   .    .    .
.  .    .              .              .
.  .    .              .              .
N  z   NaN   .    .    .    .    .   NaN
```

I hope I made my self clear, I managed to build the data up to the point I'm presenting here, but couldn't manage to go beyond that.

Guidance will be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas `apply` method to loop over rows in the main dataframe and then extract the inside dataframes to new columns. Before that you need to initialize those new columns. Here is a minimal example of what you could do:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def extract_df_to_columns(row):
    col_df = row.a
    for index, inside_row in col_df.iterrows():
        column_name = inside_row.M
        column_value = inside_row.N
        row[column_name] = column_value

    return row


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tmp_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'M': [1, 2], 'N': ['bla', 'bla1']})
    tmp_df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'M': [1, 2], 'N': ['BLA', 'BLA1']})
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [tmp_df_1, tmp_df_2], 'b': ['a', 'b']})

    list_of_new_columns = [1, 2]
    for col in list_of_new_columns:
        df[col] = np.NaN

    df = df.apply(extract_df_to_columns, axis=1)
```